# node + ts-jest + ESM, jest.mock doing nothing

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using `ts-jest` with ESM imports on `nodejs`.
The problem is that my `jest.mock` is not working, it is not mocking.

```js
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

jest.mock("./helpers"); // I tried before or after import
import { fn } from "./helpers";


describe("SimpleTest", () => {
  it("should work", () => {
    console.log(fn); // => defined
    console.log(fn.mockReturnValue); // => /!\ UNDEFINED, fn is not a jest mock.
  });
});
```

My jest config:

```js
export default {
  preset: "ts-jest/presets/default-esm",
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      useESM: true,
    },
  },
}
```

The command I use:
`node --experimental-vm-modules --experimental-specifier-resolution=node $(yarn bin jest)`

I am using node `v16.13.2` and ts-jest `27.1.3`

Answer (score 4):

`jest.mock` works for CJS, but not for ESM.

There is a `jest.unstable_mockModule` and an opened PR to turn it into a stable API, but it's in limbo (Jest author lost motivation).

For more details:

- issue [jest.mock does not mock an ES module without Babel](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10025)
- PR [feat(runtime): add jest.mockModule](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/10976)

Some valuable comments in the issue might help you find a partial solution.

It didn't work for me. I gave up on it and went a different route altogether.

Comment: I switched to `vitest`, which works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue (as mentioned in https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10025).

Basically, the issue is that Jest can't hoist the mock before all other imports as it does using babel (https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10025#issuecomment-920401080). Using a top-level await along with `jest.unstable_mockModule` worked for me.

Just to note the example using `jest.unstable_mockModule`:

```js
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

const mockFn = jest.fn();
jest.unstable_mockModule("./helpers", () => ({
  fn: mockFn
}));
const { fn } = await import("./helpers"); // Needs to be after the mock is declared.
```